# Recursion Programming in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I do not understand how this program works.

When I do it on paper the returned value is 5533110, but when I do it on PC it comes off as 53101354757824

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb341.jpg

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(long n) 
{ 
  cout << n % 10;
  if(n != 0)
  {
    f(n / 100); 
    cout << n % 10;
  }
}

int main() 
{
  cout << f(12345);
}
```

Comment: What do your function ***return***? Please take some time to learn about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get any warnings, if they were disabled, you should enable them. They're very useful.

Comment: Questions end in question-marks.

Comment: unaccept my answer and accept Stephan Lechner's answer. I honestly didn't know what your function did, all I knew is that it needed to return a value and didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do it wrong on paper; note the 2 `cout`-statements in `f`, where the `n%10`-value is printed out twice, once when the stack is increasing, and once when the stack is decreasing. So it will be `5310135` and not `5533110`.

Second, in function main, you use the return value of `f`, which is undefined when your exit condition `n==0` applies (Note that not all code paths of `f` return  value; you should actually have got a warning). That's why you see some garbage after the `5310135`. I'd suggest to use `void f(long n)`, because the function does not actually calculate a value to return but just prints out digits:

```
void f(long n) {
    cout << n % 10;
    if (n != 0)
    {
        cout << n % 10;
        f(n / 100); 
    }
}

int main() {
    f(12345);
    return 0;
}
```